# Server Monitoring: Collect data on Windows machine

Tags: linux, monitoring, performance-monitoring

Here's the situation: three servers need to be monitored, all data should be accessible on Windows machine.

Standard sensors need to be monitored:
- cpu usage
- mem usage
- disk usage

I'm out of ideas how to achieve that. There's no need for any web-based output.

Can you recommend any way?

Comment: This quesion isnt a good fit for ServerFault, please see the FAQ. http://serverfault.com/faq

Comment: Disagree- he's not asking for a product recommendation, he's asking for "how do i even do this?"

Comment: Shopping Questions are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q&A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Comment: another stupid closure reason

Comment: I disagree that this is a shopping question. He doesn't even know what types of software to look at.

Answer (score 1):

A very easy to do this is via Perfmon, Performance Monitor. Any version of Windows you want to monitor will have it, and any version of Windows that you want to collect it will have it.

Once that's done, you're going to have to manage the scheduling of this, and manage the data files that you're generating as well. Get started with that, and then ask new questions if you're having trouble.

There's a lot of other ways to do it too; you could use SNMP, or WMI, or commercial software that installs its own agent. They all have their place.